# How to connect local machine database with the looker studio mySql Extention

Tags: database, mysql-workbench, looker-studio

I have to connect a local machine database to the looker studio with MySql Extention.

I am trying to the connect my local database machine but the thing is not working because of in beetween corporate firewall.

so the firewall denied the inbound packets and got the Error on looker studio like this.

Answer (score 0):

As of [Looker Studio docs: Connect to MySQL](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7088031):

> Note: Looker Studio can't connect to localhost. You must use a public hostname or IP address.

So, to use Looker Studio MySQL Connector your Database should be publicly available.

Comment: @ Diego Queiroz Thanks for the replay. There is no any connection on publicly but my local database on 127.0.0.1 this IP on our company firewall are the denied the packet

Comment: @AdwellScott maybe you should learn a little about networking. 127.0.0.1 is a "fake" IP that means "localhost". So it is not accessible by anyone out of the local machine (and it's not due to your firewall).